# Просмотр больших XML-файлов

Tags: xml

Существуют ли программы способные отображать большие (гигабайт и больше) XML-файлы? Желательно конечно с возможностью применения XSLT

Comment: Так вам просмотр надо или XSLT-трансформатор?

Comment: Подразумевался просмотр с применением XSLT преобразования. То есть есть лог-файл. Если он размером около 10 МБ, то достаточно быстро открывается и красиво отображается в обычном IE. А вот если больше...

Comment: А, ну что вы... большие файлы не стоит открывать браузером.. будет очень долго открываться. Разумеется, надо открывать простыми утилитами, вроде тех, что в ответах уже упомянуты.

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь только утилиты вроде less могут открывать такие файлы для просмотра..
 Что же до преобразования, то попробуйте saxon с какими-нибудь жуткими параметрами запуска, чтобы памяти хватило.

Answer (score 1):

Парсить:

`http://sax.sourceforge.net/`

Посмотреть можно, например через cat:

`cat filename |more`

Под виндами я полагаю, что через far

Answer (score 0):

Notepad2